# Rename files, using text-file as source

Tags: bash, file-rename, batch-rename

In a folder, i've 600 files, numbered from 001 to 600. It looks like foo_001.bar. In a text file, i've the number & titles of this folder. Now i want to rename foo_001.bar with the corresponding 001 title foobar from the text file.

But i don't have a clue how to do this properly on Linux Mint. Can someone help me or give me a tip?

Content of the titles.txt looks like this. With a tab (can be altered easy off course) between the number and the title.

```
001 title of 1
002 this is 2
003 and here goes 3
004 number four
005 hi this is five
etc
```

Content of the folder looks like this. No exceptions.

```
file_001.ext
file_002.ext
file_003.ext
file_004.ext
file_005.ext
etc
```

Comment: Can you show us with some sample files and how you want to be renamed? it would be helpful

Comment: You want these files to be named `title of 1.ext`, `this is 2.ext`, and so on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just loop through your file with `read`, get the seperated columns with <strike>`awk`</strike> `cut` (Thank you, @Jack) and `mv` your file accordingly. In this very simple implementation I assume that your text file containing the new names is located at `./filenames` and your script is called from the directory containing your files.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        NR=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1)
        NAME=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2)
        if [ -f "foo_${NR}.ext" ] ; then
                mv "foo_${NR}.ext" "$NAME"
        fi
done < filenames
```

Comment: I know it is just a style thing, but `cut -f 1` is a lot simpler than `awk -F '\t' '{print $1}'`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Did some little altering, but it worked :-) What i was wondering, why is the filenames mentioned at the end? It has to be there, but .. why?

Comment: You need to feed `read` with some input to actually read from. This is done by piping the content of the file `filenames` into the `while read; do...`loop.

Comment: Hi. Terminal says "done" but nothing was done. Is this the correct syntax? First off, I am in the directory of the movie files files I want to change. The movies and list.text are in the same directory `
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
        NR=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 1)
        NAME=$(echo "$line" | cut -f 2)
        if [ -f "foo_${NR}.mp4" ] ; then
                mv "foo_${NR}.mp4" "$NAME"
        fi
done < /Users/edison/Downloads/movies/list.txt`